# Is it possible to code output that reacts to user input?

Tags: html

I am currently working on an application for my girlfriend to help her track important things in her life. This may be a rather trivial question but I admit I am still new to html and css.

Is there a process I can code that will print out text one line at a time, and wait for her input before moving on to the next?

For example:

```
<p>
    First line of text.
    Second line of text.
    Third line of text.
</p>
```

This currently prints all lines at once.
Is there a method for printing each one reactively to user input?

For example:

> "First line of text"
>
> stop
>
> wait for user input
>
> "Second line of text"
>
> stop
>
> wait for user input
>
> etc

I know this is probably something easy, but I figured asking the question might help fellow people new to html learn from my issue.

Comment: Not with HTML, no.

Comment: How about with a JSP page?

Comment: Of course, this is possible. I assume your exame is a simplistic case. JavaScript is good for dynamic DOM manipulation. If you want to interact with dynamic information on the server, then you'd want to to consider what technology to.use there. The choice really depends upon a deeper understanding of your requirements.

Comment: Right, so I'm a Java developer currently who is trying to learn html, css, and javascript in order to get a better grasp of web developing. If the best technology for this would be javascript I can definitely research that and convert my html page to a jsp. I will be using a servlet for the back end too, if that helps.

Comment: how about programing an app in native? android studio or swift for example?

Comment: I could potentially try to code this in Android Studio, yes. I am just not super familiar and not sure of the benefit compared to a web application.

Comment: What do you mean by 'a line,' a line of text will have different lengths with varying viewport sizes. Should this look like text - a story or prose - revealing itself line-by-line, or is it more like a list, each list-item revealing itself entry-by-entry?

Comment: Thats a good question. I would like it to be more of a story revealing itself line by line. For instance, it would print out “Hello Person!” then wait either a set amount of time or for user input to the next text line “How are you?”.

Comment: So more sentence-by-sentence..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach towards the effect you're looking to achieve, using HTML, CSS and Javascript.

Please ask follow-up questions in the comments below if there is anything in this setup which doesn't immediately make sense.

**Working Example:**

```js
let form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];

const revealLine = () => {

  let textLineNumber = document.querySelectorAll('[data-revealed="true"]').length;
  
  if (textLineNumber < 3) {
    
    let textLine = document.getElementsByTagName('label')[textLineNumber];
    textLine.dataset.revealed = 'true';
    textLine.focus();
  }
}

setTimeout(revealLine, 20);

form.addEventListener('change', revealLine, false);
```

```css
label {
margin-bottom: 12px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(191, 191, 191);
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

label[data-revealed],
label[data-revealed] + input {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  height: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
}

label[data-revealed] {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: opacity 2s linear;
}

label[data-revealed="false"],
label[data-revealed="false"] + input {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
<label data-revealed="false" for="line1">This is the first line of text (type something below and press return)</label>
<input type="text" id="line1" />
<label data-revealed="false" for="line2">This is the second line of text (type something below and press return)</label>
<input type="text" id="line2" />
<label data-revealed="false" for="line3">This is the third line of text</label>
<input type="text" id="line3" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I think this will be perfect for getting it where I want it to be!